# How to use set.seed() globally in R Markdown?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

Can someone please provide a working example of how to use set.seed() globally in R Markdown?  I am aware of [Yihui's documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/) based on [this bug report](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/274), but I get an error message when I put the suggested option in my setup chunk as `knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = rand_seed)`.

What am I missing?  I currently just have a random seed in the first code chunk that needs it, but later chunks should use the same seed.

[UPDATE BELOW]

My setup chunk:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
#knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "/Users/Zack/Documents/UCLA/Courses/PP290_NetworkScience")
#library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=80),tidy=TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = rand_seed)
```
````

Error:

```
Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
Error in knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = rand_seed) : 
  object 'rand_seed' not found
```

The chunk that uses a seed is this:

````
```{r section1_3, error=TRUE, cache=FALSE, eval=TRUE, echo=TRUE}
set.seed(01082017)
# A binomial distribution is one that produces a series of numbers according to parameters you pass it.
# We can easily make it produces 1s and 0s and then populate an adjacency matrix with them.
# The last argument controls the ratio of 1s and 0s.  So, half the output will be 1, half will be 0, on average.
rbinom(1,1,.5)
rbinom(1,1,.5)
rbinom(1,1,.5)
rbinom(1,1,.5)
rbinom(1,1,.5)
```
````

For now, I have removed `knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = rand_seed)` from my R Markdown file.

Comment: I edited this to make it not a "reference request" -- otherwise it is going to get closed.  It sounds like a valid question to me.  Some more info on the error message might be helpful.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean? If you set the seed in the first chunk, the following chunks will be using the same initial seed value.

Comment: that's a very old issue and you haven't provided a reproducible example of what's not working. even with `cache=TRUE` in intermediate chunks I get reproducible results.

Comment: Updated.  Do I put set.seed() in the setup chunk?

Comment: I am aware that it is an old issue, but the documentation is not clear to me.  Does the information I have added help?

Comment: `rand_seed` is exported from `knitr`, so you probably need to run `knitr::rand_seed` instead of just `rand_seed`

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem and I think I've fixed it... put the seed inside the first chunk and make `cache = TRUE` in the `knitr` options. I hope it helps you!

```
{r, set.seed(333)}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache = T)

[your code here]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the knitr library first.

```
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=80),tidy=TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = rand_seed)
```

Answer (score 0):

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
#knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE) knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = 
"/Users/Zack/Documents/UCLA/Courses/PP290_NetworkScience")
#library(knitr) 
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=80),tidy=TRUE) 
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = rand_seed)
```
````

Did you try to uncomment library(knitr)?

Comment: `knitr::opts_chunks$set` will load the package into memory anyway (without attaching the namespace)